# How to get cloud object storage information after it's ordered on softlayer?

Tags: object, storage, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, account

I order a cloud object storage on softlayer through following method:

> > > order={'prices': [{'id': 177725}], 'packageId': 206, 'quantity': 1}
> > >
> > > result = client['SoftLayer_Product_Order'].placeOrder(order)

And I can see that the order is passed and cloud object storage is created. Then I want to get credentials info so I need to get account name first. But from the information output:

> > > pp.pprint(result)

I have no idea to use which parameter to determine the cloud object storage created just now.

Q1: How can I get the account name or ID info for the cloud object storage created just now?

Q2: Is there any way to config account name when order cloud object storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: You can get through **orderId** generated in the response from placeOrder method, here a part of code:

```
objectFilter = {"networkStorage": {"billingItem": {"orderItem": {"order": {"id":{"operation": 123123}}}}}}

result  = client['SoftLayer_Account'].getNetworkStorage(filter=objectFilter)
```

Replace: 123123 with the orderId generated in placeOrder method response

Q2: Unfortunately, its not possible to config the account name